# SQL запрос с выводом трёх колонок в формате char - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос SQL:

```
SELECT 
    case when json_extract_path_text between (select admission_date from mc_step where id = 18731871) and to_date('09.03.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
    then 
    true
    else false
    end
    from cast (json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements('[{"bdate":"08.03.2016"}]'::json),'bdate') as date);
```

Но он выводит только одну колонку - case t или f. Как изменить запрос, чтобы он еще вывел помимо первой колонки, еще вторую как дату 
admission_date и третью колонку to_date('09.03.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') в формате char.

Comment: через запятую перечисляйте все необходимые колонки

Comment: может подскажешь синтаксис?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    admission_date
    ,to_date('09.03.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
    ,case 
        when json_extract_path_text 
            between (select admission_date from mc_step where id = 18731871) 
            and to_date('09.03.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
        then true
        else false
    end
from cast (json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements('[{"bdate":"08.03.2016"}]'::json),'bdate') as date);
```